# Gitlab issue templates for Groups?

Tags: gitlab, issue-tracking

We have recently decided to create some default templates for our projects, I know I can do that by adding some markdown files to a `.gitlab/issue_templates` directory in the root of my projects.

My issue is that we have hundreds of projects divided into different Groups, and I'd rather avoid modifying every single one of them. Is it possible to create some sort of *Group issue templates* that will affect all projects within a certain Group?
I'm aware that this is possible in Github Organizations, for example, by creating a `.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATES` directory in the root Organization's `.github` repository, is something similar possible to achieve with Gitlab?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you can archive this through GitLab Project Templates for groups: [Docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/description_templates.html#set-group-level-description-templates)

1. On the top bar, select Menu > Groups and find your group.
2. On the left sidebar, select Settings > General.
3. Expand Templates.
4. From the dropdown list, select your template project as the template repository at group level.
5. Select Save changes.

Comment: Thanks, sadly it looks like its only available for Premium users, so I guess I'll have to do it manually in my case

Comment: Is there a way to remove templates?

Comment: this only seems to work for a given group, the drop down doesn't allow to go get the template repository from e.g. two levels above or at the organization root